# What version of FSharp.Data is compatible with MSVS 2013?

Tags: f#, f#-data

There is an empty F# project open in Visual Studio 2013.

```
open System

[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv =
    printfn "%A" argv
    System.Console.ReadKey() |> ignore
    0
```

As soon as I install FSharp.Data package, the project stops to compile with the following error:

```
The design-time type 'System.String' utilized by a type provider was not found in the target reference assembly set '[tgt assembly FSharp.Data, Version=3.3.3.0, Culture=neutral]'. 
You may be referencing a profile which contains fewer types than those needed by the type provider you are using.   
parse error FS3033
```

Not sure if it's relevant but NuGet also installed FSharp.Core 4.0.0.1 even though MSVS 2013 comes with FSharp.Core 4.3.0.0 and 4.3.1.0

MSVS upgrade is not an option in my case.

So the question is how can I use F# type providers in MSVS 2013 project targeting .NET 4.5?

Comment: I don't have VS 2013 on hand to test, but it was released in Nov. 2013, so I think your best bet for FSharp.Data might be version 2.x, which was first released in Mar. 2014. See version history at https://www.nuget.org/packages/FSharp.Data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible. Newer versions Type Providers won't load in older Visual Studio versions. If you cannot upgrade your Visual Studio version, try and older version of the type provider, such as version 2.0.0.